# What is anger. How it is different from violence?

Tags: fetters

I want the differences between the two, followed by their definitions?

Comment: See also [What is the etymology of “byāpā­da­”](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/19955/254)

Answer (score 4):

Anger refers to a mental state. Violence usually refers to a destructive or harmful physical action caused by an angry mental state. Both are originating from the defilment called [Dosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvesha_(Buddhism))(aversion).

Answer (score 0):

[Violence](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.176.than.html) is like setting another person or thing on fire. [Anger](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an07/an07.060.nymo.html) is like setting yourself on fire.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a  sutta about angry men and women

http://obo.genaud.net/dhamma-vinaya/ati/an/07_sevens/an07.060.than.ati.htm

Comment: Does it explain the difference between violence and anger?

Answer (score 0):

You tagged the question [fetters](/questions/tagged/fetters), and [therefore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetter_(Buddhism)) perhaps the "anger" you're referring to is [byāpā­da­](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/19955/254) or perhaps it's [paṭigha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratigha).

I'm not sure what "violence" is (i.e. what word it is, whose definition you want). There is a chapter in the Dhammapada whose title is translated as [Violence](https://suttacentral.net/dhp129-145/en/buddharakkhita), that's the *Daṇḍavagga* in Pali, i.e. "the chapter about *daṇḍa*" -- see [a definition here](https://suttacentral.net/define/da%E1%B9%87%E1%B8%8Da).